# Azure create filename from blob name in nLog.config

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, nlog, logfile

I am newbie to Azure and just digging out to my first task. we are creating logs file for error logs.

I want to create 4 diff. which has logs of 6 hours from starting of the day. Please find below my nlog.config code:

```xml
    <target type="AzureBlobStorage"
        name="Trace-BlobStorageLogger"
        layout=""
        connectionString=""
        container=""
        blobName="nlog-storage-trace-test-${date:format=dd-MM-yyyy}.txt"/>
```

Right now, it generating one file for whole day, but due to storage capacity once it is full then after logs are not logging.

We want to divide it into 6 hours each into 4 files. We want file to be created  something like:

- nlog-storage-trace-test-10-06-2020-0000-0600.txt
- nlog-storage-trace-test-10-06-2020-0600-1200.txt
- and so on.

What change is needed in blobName in target tag in nlog.config file or nay other change that fulfills my requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "new" NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage will reduce the number of writes, so it stay below 50000 file-operations per day:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/

But if you want the filename to "expire" every 6 hours, then I guess you can use [cachedSeconds](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Cached-Layout-Renderer) do this:

```
<target type="AzureBlobStorage"
          name="Trace-BlobStorageLogger"
          blobName="nlog-storage-trace-test-${date:format=dd-MM-yyyy_hhmm:cachedSeconds=21600}.txt"/>
```

Alternative you can write/register your own [custom NLog LayoutRenderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer):